# spring hibernate .. H2 database - schema not found

Tags: java, spring, hibernate, persistence, h2

I am trying to persist some data into the H2 database. but I keep getting the schema not found error message as below.

```
Jan 02, 2014 8:55:51 PM org.apache.catalina.core.AprLifecycleListener init
INFO: The APR based Apache Tomcat Native library which allows optimal performance in production environments was not found on the java.library.path: C:\Program Files\Java\jdk1.7.0_45\bin;C:\windows\Sun\Java\bin;C:\windows\system32;C:\windows;M:\app\oracleuser\product\12.1.0\dbhome_1\bin;C:\Program Files\Common Files\Microsoft Shared\Windows Live;C:\Program Files (x86)\Common Files\Microsoft Shared\Windows Live;C:\Program Files (x86)\Intel\iCLS Client\;C:\Program Files\Intel\iCLS Client\;C:\windows\system32;C:\windows;C:\windows\System32\Wbem;C:\windows\System32\WindowsPowerShell\v1.0\;C:\Program Files\ThinkPad\Bluetooth Software\;C:\Program Files\ThinkPad\Bluetooth Software\syswow64;;C:\Program Files\Intel\Intel(R) Management Engine Components\DAL;C:\Program Files\Intel\Intel(R) Management Engine Components\IPT;C:\Program Files (x86)\Intel\Intel(R) Management Engine Components\DAL;C:\Program Files (x86)\Intel\Intel(R) Management Engine Components\IPT;C:\Program Files (x86)\Intel\OpenCL SDK\2.0\bin\x86;C:\Program Files (x86)\Intel\OpenCL SDK\2.0\bin\x64;C:\Program Files\Common Files\Lenovo;C:\Program Files (x86)\Common Files\Ulead Systems\MPEG;C:\Program Files (x86)\Windows Live\Shared;C:\SWTOOLS\ReadyApps;C:\Program Files (x86)\Symantec\VIP Access Client\;C:\Program Files (x86)\Common Files\Lenovo;C:\Program Files\Java\jdk1.7.0_45\bin;M:\maven\apache-maven-3.1.1\bin;.
Jan 02, 2014 8:55:51 PM org.apache.tomcat.util.digester.SetPropertiesRule begin
WARNING: [SetPropertiesRule]{Server/Service/Engine/Host/Context} Setting property 'source' to 'org.eclipse.jst.jee.server:DoctorAssist' did not find a matching property.
Jan 02, 2014 8:55:51 PM org.apache.coyote.AbstractProtocol init
INFO: Initializing ProtocolHandler ["http-bio-8080"]
Jan 02, 2014 8:55:51 PM org.apache.coyote.AbstractProtocol init
INFO: Initializing ProtocolHandler ["ajp-bio-8009"]
Jan 02, 2014 8:55:51 PM org.apache.catalina.startup.Catalina load
INFO: Initialization processed in 741 ms
Jan 02, 2014 8:55:51 PM org.apache.catalina.core.StandardService startInternal
INFO: Starting service Catalina
Jan 02, 2014 8:55:51 PM org.apache.catalina.core.StandardEngine startInternal
INFO: Starting Servlet Engine: Apache Tomcat/7.0.47
Jan 02, 2014 8:55:53 PM org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationContext log
INFO: No Spring WebApplicationInitializer types detected on classpath
Jan 02, 2014 8:55:54 PM org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationContext log
INFO: Initializing Spring root WebApplicationContext
INFO : org.springframework.web.context.ContextLoader - Root WebApplicationContext: initialization started
INFO : org.springframework.web.context.support.XmlWebApplicationContext - Refreshing Root WebApplicationContext: startup date [Thu Jan 02 20:55:54 PST 2014]; root of context hierarchy
INFO : org.springframework.beans.factory.xml.XmlBeanDefinitionReader - Loading XML bean definitions from ServletContext resource [/WEB-INF/spring/hibernate-context.xml]
INFO : org.springframework.beans.factory.xml.XmlBeanDefinitionReader - Loading XML bean definitions from ServletContext resource [/WEB-INF/spring/spring-security.xml]
INFO : org.springframework.beans.factory.support.DefaultListableBeanFactory - Pre-instantiating singletons in org.springframework.beans.factory.support.DefaultListableBeanFactory@38e1ea47: defining beans [myDataSource,sessionFactory,org.springframework.security.filterChains,org.springframework.security.filterChainProxy,org.springframework.security.web.PortMapperImpl#0,org.springframework.security.web.PortResolverImpl#0,org.springframework.security.config.authentication.AuthenticationManagerFactoryBean#0,org.springframework.security.authentication.ProviderManager#0,org.springframework.security.web.context.HttpSessionSecurityContextRepository#0,org.springframework.security.web.authentication.session.SessionFixationProtectionStrategy#0,org.springframework.security.web.savedrequest.HttpSessionRequestCache#0,org.springframework.security.access.vote.AffirmativeBased#0,org.springframework.security.web.access.intercept.FilterSecurityInterceptor#0,org.springframework.security.web.access.DefaultWebInvocationPrivilegeEvaluator#0,org.springframework.security.authentication.AnonymousAuthenticationProvider#0,org.springframework.security.web.authentication.www.BasicAuthenticationEntryPoint#0,org.springframework.security.web.authentication.UsernamePasswordAuthenticationFilter#0,org.springframework.security.userDetailsServiceFactory,org.springframework.security.web.DefaultSecurityFilterChain#0,org.springframework.security.provisioning.InMemoryUserDetailsManager#0,org.springframework.security.authentication.dao.DaoAuthenticationProvider#0,org.springframework.security.authentication.DefaultAuthenticationEventPublisher#0,org.springframework.security.authenticationManager]; root of factory hierarchy
INFO : org.hibernate.annotations.common.Version - HCANN000001: Hibernate Commons Annotations {4.0.1.Final}
INFO : org.hibernate.Version - HHH000412: Hibernate Core {4.2.0.Final}
INFO : org.hibernate.cfg.Environment - HHH000206: hibernate.properties not found
INFO : org.hibernate.cfg.Environment - HHH000021: Bytecode provider name : javassist
INFO : org.hibernate.dialect.Dialect - HHH000400: Using dialect: org.hibernate.dialect.H2Dialect
INFO : org.hibernate.engine.transaction.internal.TransactionFactoryInitiator - HHH000399: Using default transaction strategy (direct JDBC transactions)
INFO : org.hibernate.hql.internal.ast.ASTQueryTranslatorFactory - HHH000397: Using ASTQueryTranslatorFactory
INFO : org.springframework.web.context.ContextLoader - Root WebApplicationContext: initialization completed in 1861 ms
Jan 02, 2014 8:55:56 PM org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationContext log
INFO: Initializing Spring FrameworkServlet 'appServlet'
INFO : org.springframework.web.servlet.DispatcherServlet - FrameworkServlet 'appServlet': initialization started
INFO : org.springframework.web.context.support.XmlWebApplicationContext - Refreshing WebApplicationContext for namespace 'appServlet-servlet': startup date [Thu Jan 02 20:55:56 PST 2014]; parent: Root WebApplicationContext
INFO : org.springframework.beans.factory.xml.XmlBeanDefinitionReader - Loading XML bean definitions from ServletContext resource [/WEB-INF/spring/appServlet/servlet-context.xml]
INFO : org.springframework.context.annotation.ClassPathBeanDefinitionScanner - JSR-250 'javax.annotation.ManagedBean' found and supported for component scanning
INFO : org.springframework.context.annotation.ClassPathBeanDefinitionScanner - JSR-330 'javax.inject.Named' annotation found and supported for component scanning
INFO : org.springframework.context.annotation.ClassPathBeanDefinitionScanner - JSR-250 'javax.annotation.ManagedBean' found and supported for component scanning
INFO : org.springframework.context.annotation.ClassPathBeanDefinitionScanner - JSR-330 'javax.inject.Named' annotation found and supported for component scanning
INFO : org.springframework.beans.factory.annotation.AutowiredAnnotationBeanPostProcessor - JSR-330 'javax.inject.Inject' annotation found and supported for autowiring
INFO : org.springframework.beans.factory.support.DefaultListableBeanFactory - Pre-instantiating singletons in org.springframework.beans.factory.support.DefaultListableBeanFactory@2dbe2bb7: defining beans [mvcContentNegotiationManager,org.springframework.web.servlet.mvc.method.annotation.RequestMappingHandlerMapping#0,org.springframework.format.support.FormattingConversionServiceFactoryBean#0,org.springframework.web.servlet.mvc.method.annotation.RequestMappingHandlerAdapter#0,org.springframework.web.servlet.handler.MappedInterceptor#0,org.springframework.web.servlet.mvc.method.annotation.ExceptionHandlerExceptionResolver#0,org.springframework.web.servlet.mvc.annotation.ResponseStatusExceptionResolver#0,org.springframework.web.servlet.mvc.support.DefaultHandlerExceptionResolver#0,org.springframework.web.servlet.handler.BeanNameUrlHandlerMapping,org.springframework.web.servlet.mvc.HttpRequestHandlerAdapter,org.springframework.web.servlet.mvc.SimpleControllerHandlerAdapter,org.springframework.web.servlet.resource.ResourceHttpRequestHandler#0,org.springframework.web.servlet.handler.SimpleUrlHandlerMapping#0,org.springframework.web.servlet.view.InternalResourceViewResolver#0,homeController,patientDataController,ReadXMLService,org.springframework.context.annotation.internalConfigurationAnnotationProcessor,org.springframework.context.annotation.internalAutowiredAnnotationProcessor,org.springframework.context.annotation.internalRequiredAnnotationProcessor,org.springframework.context.annotation.internalCommonAnnotationProcessor,org.springframework.context.annotation.internalPersistenceAnnotationProcessor,hibernateDaoImpl,org.springframework.context.annotation.ConfigurationClassPostProcessor.importAwareProcessor]; parent: org.springframework.beans.factory.support.DefaultListableBeanFactory@38e1ea47
INFO : org.springframework.web.servlet.mvc.method.annotation.RequestMappingHandlerMapping - Mapped "{[/home],methods=[GET],params=[],headers=[],consumes=[],produces=[],custom=[]}" onto public java.lang.String com.mycompany.myapp.HomeController.home(org.springframework.ui.Model,java.security.Principal)
INFO : org.springframework.web.servlet.mvc.method.annotation.RequestMappingHandlerMapping - Mapped "{[/login],methods=[GET],params=[],headers=[],consumes=[],produces=[],custom=[]}" onto public java.lang.String com.mycompany.myapp.HomeController.login(java.util.Locale,org.springframework.ui.Model)
INFO : org.springframework.web.servlet.mvc.method.annotation.RequestMappingHandlerMapping - Mapped "{[/loginfailed],methods=[GET],params=[],headers=[],consumes=[],produces=[],custom=[]}" onto public java.lang.String com.mycompany.myapp.HomeController.loginfailed(java.util.Locale,org.springframework.ui.Model)
INFO : org.springframework.web.servlet.mvc.method.annotation.RequestMappingHandlerMapping - Mapped "{[/appointments],methods=[GET],params=[],headers=[],consumes=[],produces=[],custom=[]}" onto public java.lang.String com.mycompany.myapp.HomeController.appointments(org.springframework.ui.Model,java.security.Principal)
INFO : org.springframework.web.servlet.mvc.method.annotation.RequestMappingHandlerMapping - Mapped "{[/personal],methods=[GET],params=[],headers=[],consumes=[],produces=[],custom=[]}" onto public java.lang.String com.mycompany.myapp.HomeController.personal(java.util.Locale,org.springframework.ui.Model)
INFO : org.springframework.web.servlet.mvc.method.annotation.RequestMappingHandlerMapping - Mapped "{[/success],methods=[POST],params=[],headers=[],consumes=[],produces=[],custom=[]}" onto public java.lang.String com.mycompany.myapp.PatientDataController.success(java.util.Locale,org.springframework.ui.Model)
INFO : org.springframework.web.servlet.mvc.method.annotation.RequestMappingHandlerMapping - Mapped "{[/patientdata],methods=[GET],params=[],headers=[],consumes=[],produces=[],custom=[]}" onto public java.lang.String com.mycompany.myapp.PatientDataController.patientdata(java.util.Locale,org.springframework.ui.Model)
INFO : org.springframework.web.servlet.handler.SimpleUrlHandlerMapping - Mapped URL path [/resources/**] onto handler 'org.springframework.web.servlet.resource.ResourceHttpRequestHandler#0'
INFO : org.springframework.web.servlet.DispatcherServlet - FrameworkServlet 'appServlet': initialization completed in 1107 ms
Jan 02, 2014 8:55:57 PM org.apache.catalina.startup.HostConfig deployDirectory
INFO: Deploying web application directory M:\apache-tomcat-7.0.47-windows-x64\apache-tomcat-7.0.47\webapps\docs
Jan 02, 2014 8:55:57 PM org.apache.catalina.startup.HostConfig deployDirectory
INFO: Deploying web application directory M:\apache-tomcat-7.0.47-windows-x64\apache-tomcat-7.0.47\webapps\examples
Jan 02, 2014 8:55:57 PM org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationContext log
INFO: ContextListener: contextInitialized()
Jan 02, 2014 8:55:57 PM org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationContext log
INFO: SessionListener: contextInitialized()
Jan 02, 2014 8:55:57 PM org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationContext log
INFO: ContextListener: attributeAdded('org.apache.jasper.compiler.TldLocationsCache', 'org.apache.jasper.compiler.TldLocationsCache@5c487995')
Jan 02, 2014 8:55:57 PM org.apache.catalina.startup.HostConfig deployDirectory
INFO: Deploying web application directory M:\apache-tomcat-7.0.47-windows-x64\apache-tomcat-7.0.47\webapps\host-manager
Jan 02, 2014 8:55:57 PM org.apache.catalina.startup.HostConfig deployDirectory
INFO: Deploying web application directory M:\apache-tomcat-7.0.47-windows-x64\apache-tomcat-7.0.47\webapps\manager
Jan 02, 2014 8:55:57 PM org.apache.catalina.startup.HostConfig deployDirectory
INFO: Deploying web application directory M:\apache-tomcat-7.0.47-windows-x64\apache-tomcat-7.0.47\webapps\ROOT
Jan 02, 2014 8:55:57 PM org.apache.coyote.AbstractProtocol start
INFO: Starting ProtocolHandler ["http-bio-8080"]
Jan 02, 2014 8:55:57 PM org.apache.coyote.AbstractProtocol start
INFO: Starting ProtocolHandler ["ajp-bio-8009"]
Jan 02, 2014 8:55:57 PM org.apache.catalina.startup.Catalina start
INFO: Server startup in 6266 ms
INFO : com.mycompany.myapp.HomeController - login
INFO : com.mycompany.myapp.HomeController - Welcome home! The client locale is {}.
INFO : com.mycompany.myapp.PatientDataController - patient data in the new PatientDataController controller
Hibernate: insert into DOCTORASSIST.Patient (age, first_name, last_name, pid) values (?, ?, ?, ?)
WARN : org.hibernate.engine.jdbc.spi.SqlExceptionHelper - SQL Error: 90079, SQLState: 90079
ERROR: org.hibernate.engine.jdbc.spi.SqlExceptionHelper - Schema "DOCTORASSIST" not found; SQL statement:
insert into DOCTORASSIST.Patient (age, first_name, last_name, pid) values (?, ?, ?, ?) [90079-174]
Jan 02, 2014 9:00:46 PM org.apache.catalina.core.StandardWrapperValve invoke
SEVERE: Servlet.service() for servlet [appServlet] in context with path [/myapp] threw exception [Request processing failed; nested exception is org.hibernate.exception.GenericJDBCException: could not prepare statement] with root cause
org.h2.jdbc.JdbcSQLException: Schema "DOCTORASSIST" not found; SQL statement:
insert into DOCTORASSIST.Patient (age, first_name, last_name, pid) values (?, ?, ?, ?) [90079-174]
    at org.h2.message.DbException.getJdbcSQLException(DbException.java:332)
    at org.h2.message.DbException.get(DbException.java:172)
    at org.h2.message.DbException.get(DbException.java:149)
    at org.h2.command.Parser.getSchema(Parser.java:626)
    at org.h2.command.Parser.getSchema(Parser.java:633)
    at org.h2.command.Parser.readTableOrView(Parser.java:4884)
    at org.h2.command.Parser.readTableOrView(Parser.java:4878)
    at org.h2.command.Parser.parseInsert(Parser.java:984)
    at org.h2.command.Parser.parsePrepared(Parser.java:385)
    at org.h2.command.Parser.parse(Parser.java:289)
    at org.h2.command.Parser.parse(Parser.java:261)
    at org.h2.command.Parser.prepareCommand(Parser.java:226)
    at org.h2.engine.Session.prepareLocal(Session.java:437)
    at org.h2.engine.Session.prepareCommand(Session.java:380)
    at org.h2.jdbc.JdbcConnection.prepareCommand(JdbcConnection.java:1138)
    at org.h2.jdbc.JdbcPreparedStatement.<init>(JdbcPreparedStatement.java:70)
    at org.h2.jdbc.JdbcConnection.prepareStatement(JdbcConnection.java:267)
    at org.hibernate.engine.jdbc.internal.StatementPreparerImpl$1.doPrepare(StatementPreparerImpl.java:98)
    at org.hibernate.engine.jdbc.internal.StatementPreparerImpl$StatementPreparationTemplate.prepareStatement(StatementPreparerImpl.java:182)
    at org.hibernate.engine.jdbc.internal.StatementPreparerImpl.prepareStatement(StatementPreparerImpl.java:91)
    at org.hibernate.engine.jdbc.batch.internal.AbstractBatchImpl.buildBatchStatement(AbstractBatchImpl.java:138)
    at org.hibernate.engine.jdbc.batch.internal.AbstractBatchImpl.getBatchStatement(AbstractBatchImpl.java:127)
    at org.hibernate.persister.entity.AbstractEntityPersister.insert(AbstractEntityPersister.java:3036)
    at org.hibernate.persister.entity.AbstractEntityPersister.insert(AbstractEntityPersister.java:3499)
    at org.hibernate.action.internal.EntityInsertAction.execute(EntityInsertAction.java:88)
    at org.hibernate.engine.spi.ActionQueue.execute(ActionQueue.java:362)
    at org.hibernate.engine.spi.ActionQueue.executeActions(ActionQueue.java:354)
    at org.hibernate.engine.spi.ActionQueue.executeActions(ActionQueue.java:275)
    at org.hibernate.event.internal.AbstractFlushingEventListener.performExecutions(AbstractFlushingEventListener.java:328)
    at org.hibernate.event.internal.DefaultFlushEventListener.onFlush(DefaultFlushEventListener.java:52)
    at org.hibernate.internal.SessionImpl.flush(SessionImpl.java:1233)
    at org.hibernate.internal.SessionImpl.managedFlush(SessionImpl.java:403)
    at org.hibernate.engine.transaction.internal.jdbc.JdbcTransaction.beforeTransactionCommit(JdbcTransaction.java:101)
    at org.hibernate.engine.transaction.spi.AbstractTransactionImpl.commit(AbstractTransactionImpl.java:175)
    at com.mycompany.myapp.PatientDataController.patientdata(PatientDataController.java:53)
    at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke0(Native Method)
    at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(NativeMethodAccessorImpl.java:57)
    at sun.reflect.DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.java:43)
    at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:606)
    at org.springframework.web.method.support.InvocableHandlerMethod.invoke(InvocableHandlerMethod.java:219)
    at org.springframework.web.method.support.InvocableHandlerMethod.invokeForRequest(InvocableHandlerMethod.java:132)
    at org.springframework.web.servlet.mvc.method.annotation.ServletInvocableHandlerMethod.invokeAndHandle(ServletInvocableHandlerMethod.java:104)
    at org.springframework.web.servlet.mvc.method.annotation.RequestMappingHandlerAdapter.invokeHandleMethod(RequestMappingHandlerAdapter.java:745)
    at org.springframework.web.servlet.mvc.method.annotation.RequestMappingHandlerAdapter.handleInternal(RequestMappingHandlerAdapter.java:686)
    at org.springframework.web.servlet.mvc.method.AbstractHandlerMethodAdapter.handle(AbstractHandlerMethodAdapter.java:80)
    at org.springframework.web.servlet.DispatcherServlet.doDispatch(DispatcherServlet.java:925)
    at org.springframework.web.servlet.DispatcherServlet.doService(DispatcherServlet.java:856)
    at org.springframework.web.servlet.FrameworkServlet.processRequest(FrameworkServlet.java:936)
    at org.springframework.web.servlet.FrameworkServlet.doGet(FrameworkServlet.java:827)
    at javax.servlet.http.HttpServlet.service(HttpServlet.java:621)
    at org.springframework.web.servlet.FrameworkServlet.service(FrameworkServlet.java:812)
    at javax.servlet.http.HttpServlet.service(HttpServlet.java:728)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.internalDoFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:305)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.doFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:210)
    at org.apache.tomcat.websocket.server.WsFilter.doFilter(WsFilter.java:51)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.internalDoFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:243)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.doFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:210)
    at org.springframework.security.web.FilterChainProxy$VirtualFilterChain.doFilter(FilterChainProxy.java:330)
    at org.springframework.security.web.access.intercept.FilterSecurityInterceptor.invoke(FilterSecurityInterceptor.java:118)
    at org.springframework.security.web.access.intercept.FilterSecurityInterceptor.doFilter(FilterSecurityInterceptor.java:84)
    at org.springframework.security.web.FilterChainProxy$VirtualFilterChain.doFilter(FilterChainProxy.java:342)
    at org.springframework.security.web.access.ExceptionTranslationFilter.doFilter(ExceptionTranslationFilter.java:113)
    at org.springframework.security.web.FilterChainProxy$VirtualFilterChain.doFilter(FilterChainProxy.java:342)
    at org.springframework.security.web.session.SessionManagementFilter.doFilter(SessionManagementFilter.java:103)
    at org.springframework.security.web.FilterChainProxy$VirtualFilterChain.doFilter(FilterChainProxy.java:342)
    at org.springframework.security.web.authentication.AnonymousAuthenticationFilter.doFilter(AnonymousAuthenticationFilter.java:113)
    at org.springframework.security.web.FilterChainProxy$VirtualFilterChain.doFilter(FilterChainProxy.java:342)
    at org.springframework.security.web.servletapi.SecurityContextHolderAwareRequestFilter.doFilter(SecurityContextHolderAwareRequestFilter.java:54)
    at org.springframework.security.web.FilterChainProxy$VirtualFilterChain.doFilter(FilterChainProxy.java:342)
    at org.springframework.security.web.savedrequest.RequestCacheAwareFilter.doFilter(RequestCacheAwareFilter.java:45)
    at org.springframework.security.web.FilterChainProxy$VirtualFilterChain.doFilter(FilterChainProxy.java:342)
    at org.springframework.security.web.authentication.www.BasicAuthenticationFilter.doFilter(BasicAuthenticationFilter.java:150)
    at org.springframework.security.web.FilterChainProxy$VirtualFilterChain.doFilter(FilterChainProxy.java:342)
    at org.springframework.security.web.authentication.AbstractAuthenticationProcessingFilter.doFilter(AbstractAuthenticationProcessingFilter.java:183)
    at org.springframework.security.web.FilterChainProxy$VirtualFilterChain.doFilter(FilterChainProxy.java:342)
    at org.springframework.security.web.authentication.logout.LogoutFilter.doFilter(LogoutFilter.java:105)
    at org.springframework.security.web.FilterChainProxy$VirtualFilterChain.doFilter(FilterChainProxy.java:342)
    at org.springframework.security.web.context.SecurityContextPersistenceFilter.doFilter(SecurityContextPersistenceFilter.java:87)
    at org.springframework.security.web.FilterChainProxy$VirtualFilterChain.doFilter(FilterChainProxy.java:342)
    at org.springframework.security.web.FilterChainProxy.doFilterInternal(FilterChainProxy.java:192)
    at org.springframework.security.web.FilterChainProxy.doFilter(FilterChainProxy.java:160)
    at org.springframework.web.filter.DelegatingFilterProxy.invokeDelegate(DelegatingFilterProxy.java:343)
    at org.springframework.web.filter.DelegatingFilterProxy.doFilter(DelegatingFilterProxy.java:260)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.internalDoFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:243)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.doFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:210)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardWrapperValve.invoke(StandardWrapperValve.java:222)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardContextValve.invoke(StandardContextValve.java:123)
    at org.apache.catalina.authenticator.AuthenticatorBase.invoke(AuthenticatorBase.java:502)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardHostValve.invoke(StandardHostValve.java:171)
    at org.apache.catalina.valves.ErrorReportValve.invoke(ErrorReportValve.java:100)
    at org.apache.catalina.valves.AccessLogValve.invoke(AccessLogValve.java:953)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardEngineValve.invoke(StandardEngineValve.java:118)
    at org.apache.catalina.connector.CoyoteAdapter.service(CoyoteAdapter.java:408)
    at org.apache.coyote.http11.AbstractHttp11Processor.process(AbstractHttp11Processor.java:1041)
    at org.apache.coyote.AbstractProtocol$AbstractConnectionHandler.process(AbstractProtocol.java:603)
    at org.apache.tomcat.util.net.JIoEndpoint$SocketProcessor.run(JIoEndpoint.java:312)
    at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor.runWorker(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:1145)
    at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor$Worker.run(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:615)
    at java.lang.Thread.run(Thread.java:744)
```

I understand that H2 is an in memory database, but i am not very familiar with it.

My applicationContext.xml looks like this.

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>

<beans xmlns="http://www.springframework.org/schema/beans"
    xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance"
    xsi:schemaLocation="http://www.springframework.org/schema/beans http://www.springframework.org/schema/beans/spring-beans.xsd">

    <!-- Root Context: defines shared resources visible to all other web components
 -->

    <bean id="myDataSource"
        class="org.springframework.jdbc.datasource.DriverManagerDataSource">
        <property name="driverClassName" value="org.h2.Driver" />
        <property name="url" value="jdbc:h2:mem:test;DB_CLOSE_DELAY=-1" />
        <property name="username" value="sa" />
        <property name="password" value="" />

    </bean>


    <bean id="sessionFactory"
        class="org.springframework.orm.hibernate4.LocalSessionFactoryBean">

        <property name="dataSource" ref="myDataSource" />
        <property name="packagesToScan" value="com.mycompany.model" />

        <property name="hibernateProperties">
            <props>
                <prop key="hibernate.dialect">org.hibernate.dialect.H2Dialect</prop>
                <prop key="hbm2ddl.auto">validate</prop>
                <prop key="hibernate.show_sql">true</prop>
                <prop key="hibernate.default_schema">DOCTORASSIST</prop>
            </props>
        </property>
    </bean>


</beans>
```

Please tell me where am I going wrong?

Comment: It sounds like the schema doesn't exist, maybe the tables don't exist either. If you try with the schema name `PUBLIC`, does it work? Or do you get a different exception?

Comment: no it doesn't work with PUBLIC. I do have the schema and the table when I open H2 from the executable jar and connect to the DB.

Answer (score 46, accepted):

The accepted answer was not fixed my problem, the working solution is to set the default schema as mentioned by **Coder**

```
<prop key="hibernate.default_schema">DOCTORASSIST</prop>
```

And also to initialize the creation of the schema:

```
<property name="hibernate.connection.url" value="jdbc:h2:mem:test;DB_CLOSE_DELAY=-1;INIT=CREATE SCHEMA IF NOT EXISTS DOCTORASSIST"/>
```

As mentioned by **user2180794** the parameter `test` is the name of the database and not the name of the schema

Comment: The Init-statement fixed the issue for me

Answer (score 14):

Upvoted accepted answer.

In my case the problem was executing `@DataJpaTest`: the initial statement to drop tables failed with error "schema not found".

Just want to share Spring Boot `application.yml` (in my case under test/resources):

```
spring:
  jpa:
    database: h2
    show-sql: true
    hibernate:
      ddl-auto: create-drop
    properties:
      hibernate:
        default_schema: metering
        connection:
          url: jdbc:h2:mem:test;DB_CLOSE_DELAY=-1;INIT=CREATE SCHEMA IF NOT EXISTS my-schema-name
      username: sa
      password:
```

Answer (score 8):

Because you've have a schema name mismatch in your configuration.

This

```
<property name="url" value="jdbc:h2:mem:test;DB_CLOSE_DELAY=-1" />
```

And this

```
<prop key="hibernate.default_schema">DOCTORASSIST</prop>
```

have a conflict.

You're jdbc URL says that your working with **test** while your hibernate.default_schema is DOCTORASSIST, make sure both values are same.

Comment: same error even when I make them the same. I thought test is the db name and doctorassist is the schema name.

Answer (score 3):

I found the mistake. it was the connection URL.

I changed the connection URL to the following

```
<property name="url" value="jdbc:h2:~/test;DB_CLOSE_DELAY=-1" />
```

referred the documentation at this location

http://www.h2database.com/html/features.html#database_url

Answer (score 0):

I solved this problem by configuring my database driver on the application server. In my case, the server is Wildfly. The configuration was made in standalone.xml and in the modules folder I put the driver jar.

Answer (score 0):

I solved this problem by just adding the annotation
`@AutoConfigureTestDatabase(replace = AutoConfigureTestDatabase.Replace.NONE)`
and updating pom dependencies

```js
<dependency>
            <groupId>mysql</groupId>
            <artifactId>mysql-connector-java</artifactId>
            <version>5.1.46</version>
        </dependency>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
            <artifactId>spring-boot-starter-test</artifactId>
            <scope>test</scope>
        </dependency>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.hibernate</groupId>
            <artifactId>hibernate-core</artifactId>
            <version>5.4.32.Final</version>
        </dependency>
```