# JdbcSQLSyntaxErrorException Schema not found

Tags: java, spring-boot, h2, database-schema, spring-boot-test

My `@SpringBootTest` is annotated with `@Sql({"classpath:create_tables_views.sql"})`

and the first line inside `create_tables_views.sql` is

```
DROP VIEW IF EXISTS my_schema.my_view;
```

When I try to run my `@SpringBootTest`, I get the following exception:

```
Caught exception while invoking 'beforeTestMethod' callback on TestExecutionListener [org.springframework.test.context.jdbc.SqlScriptsTestExecutionListener@1e0f9063] for test method [void ...] and test instance [...]
org.springframework.jdbc.datasource.init.ScriptStatementFailedException: Failed to execute SQL script statement #1 of class path resource [create_tables_views.sql]: DROP VIEW IF EXISTS my_schema.my_view; nested exception is org.h2.jdbc.JdbcSQLSyntaxErrorException: Schema "MY_SCHEMA" not found;
```

What am I missing ?

---

**UPDATE 1:**

Adding some more details here for additional clarity:
This is how my class is annotated

```
@ActiveProfiles("test") // (application-test.yml is currently empty)
@AutoConfigureTestDatabase // (so yes, it's spinning up a brand new H2 instance each time)
@AutoConfigureWebTestClient
@SpringBootTest(webEnvironment = SpringBootTest.WebEnvironment.RANDOM_PORT)
@Sql({"classpath:create_tables_views.sql"})
```

Also, upon booting, I see this in the log messages:

```
16:12:08.489 INFO  [main] o.s.j.d.e.EmbeddedDatabaseFactory: Starting embedded database: url='jdbc:h2:mem:9af3a13a-91b3-47ff-a85d-8488d2329a53;DB_CLOSE_DELAY=-1;DB_CLOSE_ON_EXIT=false', username='sa'
```

Because the initial SQL command is `DROP VIEW` **IF EXISTS** `my_schema.my_view;`, I don't understand why it is throwing an exception if the schema doesn't exist.

---

**UPDATE 2:**

In my `src/main/java` folder, I have 2 separate `@Configuration` files containing `@Bean` definitions providing `DataSource`, `LocalContainerEntityManagerFactoryBean`, and `PlatformTransactionManager` for 2 different Databases, one `@Primary` one for Postgres/Postgis and another one for Oracle.

Comment: You may append `INIT=CREATE SCHEMA IF NOT EXISTS my-schema-name;` to your connection string. Please see this answer: https://stackoverflow.com/a/66777249/4211402

Answer (score 2):

The database cannot decide if the view `my_view` exists in the schema `my_schema`, because this **schema does not exist**.

Command `DROP VIEW IF EXISTS` first retrieves metadata for the scheme `my_schema`, checks if the given view exists there, and if exists, then drops it. In your case it fails because this command cannot retrieve metadata from the schema `my_schema` because this schema does not exist.

May be you expected that it works as follows: "Check if the schema `my_schema` exists. If it doesn't exist, don't do anything more. If the schema exists, check if the view exists. Only if the view exists, issue a command to drop it." But it is not how it works. If the schema does not exist, an error is thrown.